# How can i make a logical vector

Tags: r

Sorry if my question is not very advanced. I am trying to make a Logical Vector from 1 to 10010. and I want to have the **first,** **each 100** and **the Last** as  TRUE

I tried to use `rep`for it (not important I also thought of `seq`but could not figure it out neither.

```
logical<-rep(c(FALSE),each=10010)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use `seq`

```
logical[seq(1, length(logical), by = 100)] <- TRUE
logical[length(logical)] <- TRUE
```

---

Or in a single line

```
logical2 <- seq(10010) %in% c(seq(1, 10010, by = 100), 10010)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `vector`
vector produces a vector of the given length ( in your case it is 10010) and mode which is by default logical

```
t <- vector(length = 10010)
t[seq(1, length(t), by = 100)] <- TRUE
```